# Why is the friction in the motor wrong as an answer to wasted energy in this question?

Tags: energy-conservation, work, power

I do not understand why the answer to part b)ii) cannot be energy lost to friction within the motor as the work done by the motor should be the total work done to move the cyclist and should include a value associated to the wasted energy due to friction.

As if there is a force applied by the motor to make it spin Work done should be = F*d but the work done due to friction is going to be W(wasted)=Fr*d and so the useful energy transferred should be F*d-Fr*d. I do not understand why the work done against friction in the motor is an incorrect form of wasted energy. Answers will be appreciated, thank you.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think the reason for rejection those answers is technical. I guess because it's an internal loss, not an external loss. Note how losses from both motor and rider were excluded. Either way, it's kind of a useless question to ask exam-wise.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point, the work done is assumed to be all put into moving the cyclist up. But I wanted to know what I should assume for future reference, thanks for the comment.